# Can't access the sent file from express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file

I am trying to test REST API, and I can't figure out how to send a file from client side to express server side.
This is my pug file, with which i simulate client side for specific purposes, in this case just send the picture.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Test
    body
        form(action=`${baseRoute}/api/users/${nick}/generate` enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST')
            input(type='file' accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id='profile_picture' name='image')
            input(type='submit', value='Load')
```

baseRoute is created for pug, so it does not add action link to existing link, and changes the whole link.

From what I saw, to get files from form, I have to access req.files in express back end part. Yet, it shows me absolutely nothing

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/test/update_user');
});

app.post('/api/users/:nick/generate', upload.single('image'), async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("GENERATE USER");
  console.log(req.files);
  res.send("Success");
});

app.get('/test/update_user', function(req, res, next) {
  let params = {
    baseRoute: "",
    nick: 'somenick',
  };
  res.render('test/update_user', params);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("go to localhost:3000/test/update_user");
});
```

I tried reading all of req, but there was no sight of files property. Using multer it adds a file to upload directory, but in a weird way without any extension and some weird name. And still it logs 'undefined' when I am trying to access req.files

Comment: Do you have any middleware to support files? Also: doesn't that tell you you can't assign to a function call?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, no, I don't have such middleware, No, it doesn't complain about function calls, should it?

Comment: 1. Then you'll need to add one, e.g. multer is popular. 2. Yes, `router.post('/api/users/:nick/generate') = usersController.generate_user;` is an assignment to a function call which is a reference error (and doesn't really make sense).

Comment: - I tried multer rn, and it does not help me anyhow..(

Comment: So give a [mre] _of that_.

Comment: I added the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Does `req.file` contain something?